# What folder should I apply SSL certificate to?

Tags: https, security-certificate

Is an SSL cert applied to a specific folder or also all subfolders of that folder?

If the SSL is applied to the root, will it be applied to all sub-folders?

If so why would I not always apply to root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL certificates are applied to an IP Address (optionally with associated hostname). All paths on that host are then available via encryption.

A separate issue which you may be confusing SSL with is certificate-based authentication, which can be applied at the level of any URL path unit, e.g. `/admin`